# Vue Laravel: How update a prop for a custom component

Tags: vue.js

I got this problem. I've created a component with a overlay and loading and now I want to use with other components but the " prop_show_loading " for some reason is not updated on click on the button.

```html
<template>
    <span>
        <b-btn @click="sendWelcomeEmail()" variant="primary">Send Welcome Email</b-btn>
        <loading :prop_show_loading="show_loading"></loading>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      data () {
            return {
                show_loading: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sendWelcomeEmail(){
                this.show_loading = true;
                console.log(this.show_loading);
            }
        }
   }
</script>
```

*Here my loading component where I did the logic to show the loading or modal with message.*

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="show_loading || show_modal" class="overlay">
        <div v-if="show_loading" class="spinner">
            <spinner></spinner>
        </div>
        <b-modal hide-footer v-model="show_modal" centered>
            <p class="my-4" v-if="show_success_message">{{success_message}}</p>
            <p class="my-4" v-if="show_fail_message">{{fail_message}}</p>
        </b-modal>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'prop_success_message',
            'prop_fail_message',
            'prop_show_modal',
            'prop_show_fail_message',
            'prop_show_success_message',
            'prop_show_loading'
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                show_modal : this.prop_show_modal || false ,
                fail_message: this.prop_fail_message || 'Fail',
                success_message: this.prop_success_message || 'Success',
                show_fail_message: this.prop_show_fail_message || false,
                show_success_message: this.prop_show_success_message || false,
                show_loading: this.prop_show_loading || false
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<style>
    .overlay {
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        z-index: 9999;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .spinner{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -50px;
        margin-left: -50px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

I wish someone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you saying the value of the `prop_show_loading` in your `loading` component is not changing? If so, how are you verifying this?

Comment: Yes because, en the console.log I got 'true' on click but the overlay doesn't appear! It seems that the prop_show_loading doesn't change

Comment: So where's the code or expression that actually does something with `prop_show_loading`?

Comment: Sorry, I just added in the description!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy the initial `prop` value to a `data` value, ie

```js
data () {
  return {
    // ...
    show_loading: this.prop_show_loading || false
  }
}
```

you lose any chance of detecting changes as the original reference to the prop will be broken when it gets a new value assigned.

Instead, just use the prop value in your template expressions, ie

```html
v-if="prop_show_loading"
```

This way, it will react to external changes.

---

You can do the same for all the prop values as well as define defaults. Eg

```js
props: {
  prop_success_message: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Success'
  },
  prop_fail_message: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Fail'
  },
  prop_show_modal: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  // etc...
}
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to the reason that you forgot to add "v-bind" before :prop_show_loading.
Because in Vue you need to bind the value with that particular template. So I suggest you try this and let me know if it worked for you.

Final syntax:- v-bind:prop_show_loading="show_loading"

Hope it helps

Comment: It helped me too! :)